# What is the war asset value of the Krogan Clans if Eve survived?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After the mission Priority: Tuchanka you are given some war assets, one of them is called "Krogan Clans".
It has a value of 250 because in my play trough Eve died, I didn't save Maleon data.

What is it value if Eve survive the mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eves death causes a -50 hit to the value of the Krogan Clans.

Comment: My Krogan's clan ended up closer to 600 after all was said and done, so I'm assuming based on your answer that the **base** value is 300 with Eve?

Comment: @Tristan [Yes.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Krogan)

Comment: And if you sabotage the cure, how much is the value of the salarian fleet?

Comment: Salarian 1st Fleet is worth 125. More info: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmsYTS1wvgPwdG5iX3FWX2M2UW9Pd1dBSC1hU005V3c